# Who is the hidden enemy of the Fallen One?

Tags: malazan, house-of-chains

In the opening of chapter 23 of *House of Chains*, the fourth book of *Malazan Book of the Fallen*, we read:

> Who among the pantheon would the Fallen One despise and fear the most? Consider the last chaining, in which Hood, Fener, the Queen of Dreams, Osserc and Oponn all participated, in addition to Anomander Rake, Caladan Brood and a host of other ascendants. It is not so surprising, then, that the Crippled God could not have anticipated that his deadliest enemy was not found among those mentioned...

Comment: have your read farther then this? we also know that cotillion shadowthrone, and dasem ultor were also present at this chaining. as an FYI.

Comment: Yes. I have finished the series. Most likely it would be FA. But they're not a part of the pantheon, are they?

Comment: I think its saying, that since hes not worried about anyone in the pantheon , since all of the players in the pantheon where there, who else is left to worry about? so answers don't specifically have to be part of the pantheon.

Comment: So would say that its Forkrul Assail?

Comment: im not sure, they didn't seem super interested in him, more in just harnessing him to kill humans? but well see what others think up.

Comment: There are a few possible candidates but they all end up helping him. QB, Paran. Shadowthrone and Cotillion hatched the plan of saving/sending him home. K'rul, Mael and Hood were a part of it. Olar Ethil and Draconus had their own agendas. Knuckles, Kilmandaros and Errastas' strategy was to free Korabas. I think that's all the players.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main enemies of the fallen one appears to be the old gods. They'd benefit the most from his re-chainig or taking his power for themselves.
Especialy the "boss" of old gods (sorry I can't remember his name) with his pack (Laath and Kilimandaros).

The second most likely or rather most dangerous enemy may be the forkrul asails. Well they're enemies of everyone, but with power of the fallen one on their disposal they'd be the most formidable strenght in this universe.

I mentioned only those whom would be considered as enemies of the fallen one, not those who'd benefit from his troubles/death/chaining/etc.

Comment: The "bosses" name would be Errastas. However, he is not so much the boss of the old gods, just as Ganoes Paran is not the boss of the new gods...

Comment: I did not meant that he was the boss of all of the old gods. Still he tried to gather a party of few quite powerfull ones under himself and he tried to make some noise around himself.